# jquery update a set variable in an url after refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown of data. When selected, I pipe in the `value` of the selected `option` and pipe that into the url to work with later:

```
var currentURL = document.location;
location.href = currentURL + "/" + this.simID;
```

This works great by adding the var to the end of the url. My problem is when the user then selects another `option` from the dropdown, it then obviously adds another var to the end of the previous url. I'm having a hard time trying to remove the previous `this.simID` or swapping out the variable after each refresh. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there other pathnames on the location that you want to keep. For example: is the currentUrl  = example.com or example.com/pathname1/pathname2?

Comment: example.com/something/other/also/$simID

Comment: Last 2 questions, will the other pathnames change? Also, will the $simID always be the last pathname?

Comment: the previous url (example.com/something/other/also) will never change. but i can't promise i won't move this script into another page that may have a different url path, such like example.com/here/there/everywhere. the `this.simID` is the variable i am using so yes it will always be that variable. would be nice to not have an actual refresh and maybe `preventDefault` or something...

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the location.href like so:

```
location.href = createHref(this.simID)

function createHref(option){
  var path = location.pathname.split('/'),
      lastPath = path[path.length-1],        // get the last item on the path
      options = [option1,option2,option3];   // store an array of possible options

  if (options.includes(lastPath)) {
    path.pop              // if lastPath is one of the options, remove it
  }
  path.push(option)       // then add the selected option
  return location.host + "/" + path.join('/')
}
```

This will only work if simID will always be the last item on the path.
(example.com/here/there/simID)
and not if it will be in the middle of the path
(example.com/here/simID)

Also you will need to be able to capture all the possible options.

Comment: i've provided an answer that i think is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

this seems like an elegant solution, and uses `history.pushState` to save url in history but not manually refresh the page

```
//update page url to include sim
var currentURL = location.href.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1],
    replaceURL = this.simID, //whatever var you are trying to replace in URL
    finalURL = currentURL.replace(currentURL, replaceURL);

history.pushState({id: 'LOREM IPSUM NAME'}, '', finalURL);
```